# SQL LocalDB Size Limit for Non-Express Editions

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, localdb, nosql

I have a complex Generator and I am using LocalDB to store Temporary Results.
My problem is that once the *.mdf file reaches 10.5 GB, I get an Exception regarding the "PRIMARY" FileGroup as it cannot expand.

- I did install SQL Server Enterprise 2014, though I do not know if LocalDB is affected by this.
- In Management Studio I did set the File Auto-Growth to Unlimited.

I know there is a 10 GB DataBase Size limit, but isn`t it only for the Express Edition?
I am wondering if there is any way to make the LocalDB bigger, would adding more files to the Primary Group help? (I do not think so).

Converse, if it is not possible, can anybody please recommend a free Local-NoSQL Database to use with C#?

Thank you!

Comment: You won't be able to store > 10GB of "temporary" results in LocalDB, unless you fire up multiple instances and distribute the data across them - LocalDB is subject to the same file size limitations as Express AFAIK. Why don't you store them in a scratch database in Enterprise Edition?

Answer (score 6):

There is no LocalDB edition of SQL Server outside of SQL Server Express LocalDB, which is limited to 10GB.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275.aspx

One alternative would be SQLite, which should be able to go up to [140 TB](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html), is self-contained, is serverless, and has a [.NET library](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), but it's not NoSQL, if that's really what you're looking for. (But then, why LocalDB?)

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple instances (installs) of SQL Server on the same physical box and that is what seems to be on your box (if you installed SQL Server 2012). Express has a 10GB limit and you are pointing to the 'Express' instance through your connection string. Change the connection string to point to SQL Server 2012 and you will only be limited by the amount of room on the hard disk if filegrowth is enabled.